# Coordinate Transformations (rotation)

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems

The matrix of a rotation of a point, $(x,y)$ in cartesian coordinates, counterclockwise is $$\begin{pmatrix}cosθ & -sinθ \\ sinθ & cosθ\end{pmatrix}$$

When rotating a coordinate system counterclockwise, instead of a single point, do we use the same matrix?

(The reason I'm asking this is because I've seen in some books that the matrix for coordinate system transformation be the transpose of this. And this has caused a lot of confusion.)

Comment: Yes, as the matrix is independent of the point.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Have you seen my last edit?

Comment: The transpose is the inverse and so clockwise rotation.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Yes but It didn't clarify if it was ccw or cw. So I supposed it was ccw

Comment: I think it follows from my comment that your matrix is ccw and its transpose cw rotation. You easily see this when putting $\theta = \pi/2$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Ok it was just to clarify to alleviate the confusion. Many thanks!

Comment: Here, I am assuming that $\theta > 0$. Otherwise it is the other way around.

Comment: To rotate a vector clockwise is the same as to rotate the coordinate system opposite, i.e. *counterclockwise*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you rotate a coordinate system, what you're really doing is rotating the basis vectors of the coordinate system. These are just individual vectors like any other vector you want to rotate, so the transformation matrices are unchanged.

Do be careful of the direction of rotation though! For counterclockwise it's:
\begin{align*}
R = \begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta &-\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta &\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
The clockwise rotation through $\theta$ must be the inverse of this matrix, because composing the two matrices will give zero rotation (and hence the identity matrix). Thus for clockwise,
\begin{align*}
R = \begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta &-\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta &\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}^{-1} =  \begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta &\sin\theta\\ -\sin\theta &\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Choose a point $T = [x, y]^T$ and standard basis vectors $\vec{e}_1 = [1, 0]^T, \vec{e}_2 = [0, 1]^T$.

If you want to rotate $T$ for $\theta$ counterclockwise, you can

- directly rotate $T$ using your matrix, or
- rotate the basis vectors in **the opposite direction**, so rotate them for the angle $-\theta$.

In the second case, since $\cos (-\theta) = \cos \theta$ and $\sin(-\theta) = -\sin\theta$, you will get the transpose of the matrix from the first case.

Comment: Why in the opposite direction?

Comment: Draw a sketch. It's the same as in the case when, e.g., Ana and Bob are standing $5$ meters apart, and Ana is on Bob's left. How can you make them $6$ meters apart? Either you move Ana one meter to the left or, you move Bob one meter to the right = in the opposite direction. In your case, instead of distance between $T$ and, e.g., $\vec{e}_1$, you have the angle between them.

Comment: Let $P$ be a point in the first quadrant (i.e. (1,4)). If I rotate my basis vectors (so the axes) counterclockwise, the point $P$ will be farther apart from the $y'$ axis, than it was from the $y$ axis. if I rotate them clockwise the new $y''$ axis will be closer to the point than from $y$ and $y'$. So how is this the same?

Comment: @Michael You either rotate  the **axis** counterclockwise or the **point $T$** clockwise.

Comment: Yes, nevermind, I got confused. So, if I rotate the basis vectors, then to get the new point, the coefficients of the vectors in the liinear compination will remain the same, right? $P=λe_1+μe_2$ and $P'=λe_1'+μe_2'$

Comment: @Michael Yes, if you rotate everything, the coefficients are the same. Again, draw a sketch:)